# At which moment does the fraud happens during a fraudulent transaction?

Tags: united-states, california, fraud

Does the fraud requires the fraudulent transaction to be paid or it already constitutes fraud by the time the fraudulent service or good is offered? Or is there any other moment when the fraud happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Fraud" is roughly lying to get something that isn't yours - for example, my money. It turns from attempted fraud to fraud at the point where I would be defrauded if we both take no further action. That would often be the point where I hand over the money, for example if you offer goods for sale that don't exist and that you don't intend to deliver.

If you fill out a form and forge my signature to get money, and send it off to someone who *will* give you the money, it would be fraud at the point where I lose my money if we both take no further action. That might be the second where you drop the letter in the mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took a look in the California penal code and found the section 484-502.9 (http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=pen&group=00001-01000&file=484-502.9) defining this. Yet, it appears to not define attempted fraud.

Comment: @GabrielDiego there are separate statues that define an attempt to commit a certain crime.